# Changing a word in the query string via 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to change the word "popular" to "most-popular" in the following URL

```
http://www.site.com/projects?page=12&sort=popular
```

I thought this would work:

```
RewriteRule ^projects?page=([0-9]+)&sort=popular$ http://www.site.com/projects?page=$1&sort=most-popular [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't seem to be redirecting. Can someone spot what I'm doing wrong? Am I supposed to escape anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the query string in a RewriteRule. You need to catch it in a RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([0-9]+)&sort=popular$
RewriteRule ^projects$ http://www.site.com/projects?page=%1&sort=most-popular [L,R=301]
```